# Motion deblur with unknown PSF | OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, motion-blur

For a project, I have video footage of a person walking through a museum. He films his surroundings using a smartphone and pans mostly horizontally causing a lot of motion blur. For the project, i need to be able to cut out the paintings from the video and match them with paintings from a database. The motion blur really lowers the quality of the cut-out paintings causing a lot of wrong matches. That's why I am looking for a way to remove the motion blur.

Although I have located several sources, I am struggling to incorporate them into my project. The initial source is composed in C++, and I lack the skills required to translate it to Python. The second source is composed in Python, but it employs a user-defined psf.

- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html
- http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/opencv/weiner_deconvolution_demo_gui.html

They recommended me using OpenCV but other libraries are also allowed.
Is there anyone who has a reliable source or a functional implementation for my problem that they can recommend?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **both** employ a user-defined PSF. -- what you're asking for is an active research topic. you will have to find scientific publications (papers).